# Using both print and logging in python

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to use logger for a new module. This module will be called from a top level script and this doesn't use logger mechanism, but raw print statements.

When I'm logging messages from my module, some of the characters of my statements are missing in the logfile. The no.of characters missing from my log file is equal to the no.of characters that were printed using the raw 'print' statements.

Can somebody help me in resolving this issue - ?

FYI::

1. Logger will print the messages to the log file that is being used by my top level script.
2. It's not feasible to modify the top level script to use logger instead of raw 'print' statements.
3. I'm using python 2.7.2

Code:
Logger config:

```
def initLogger(filename='debug.log', log_console_level=logging.CRITICAL):
    """
    Initialise logging routines. From debug level all log messages goes to file.
    """
    global logger
    try:
        logger = logging.getLogger("")
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handlers = []
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename, "w")
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(log_console_level)
        handlers.append(fh)
        handlers.append(ch)
        format = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)-8s] :: %(message)s')
        for i in handlers:
            i.setFormatter(format)
            logger.addHandler(i)
        logger.propagate = False

    except IOError:
        logger = logging.getLogger("")
        logging.basicConfig(format = '[%(levelname)-8s] :: %(message)s',
                            level = logging.WARN)
        logger.warn("Couldn't open %s file. Will log only to the screen" % filename)
    logger.info("Started ")
    return logger
```

Statement in top level script:

```
print "Version : 2.7.2"
```

Logger statements in my Module:

```
logger.info("Check-1 Pass\n")
```

Output in the log file:

```
Version : 2.7.2
heck-1 Pass
```

Expected output:

```
Version : 2.7.2
[INFO    ] :: Check-1 Pass
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post your code?

Comment: Added code snippets...